Can we add neq condition in Magento 2 Live search graphql search filters?
Can we add neq condition in Magento 2 Live search graphql search filters? I need to add a condition so, a specific attribute value products will not show in categories and search collections.


Create custom module.

module.xml file.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Vendor_CatalogGraphQl" setup_version="1.0.5">
<sequence>
    <module name="Magento_CatalogGraphQl"/>
</sequence>
</module>
</config>



3.di.xml file
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessor\ProductFilterProcessor" type="Magento\Eav\Model\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessor\FilterProcessor">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="customFilters" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="size" xsi:type="object">
                Vendor\CatalogGraphQl\Model\Resolver\Products\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessor\FilterProcessor\ProductAttributeFilter
            </item>
           <item name="language" xsi:type="object">
                Vendor\CatalogGraphQl\Model\Resolver\Products\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessor\FilterProcessor\ProductAttributeFilter
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

4.After this, we want to define the product attribute as FilterTypeInput to ProductFilterInput in the schema.graphqls file like below.
input ProductFilterInput {
category_url_key: FilterTypeInput @doc(description: "Category url_key the product belongs to")
category_url_path: FilterTypeInput @doc(description: "Category url_path the product belongs to")
size: FilterTypeInput @doc(description: "Product size")
language: FilterTypeInput @doc(description: "Product Language")
url_key: FilterTypeInput @doc(description: "Product url")
}

5.Create the ProductAttributeFilter.php file in the relevant directory as defined in di.xml.
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Vendor\CatalogGraphQl\Model\Resolver\Products\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessor\FilterProcessor;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessor\FilterProcessor\CustomFilterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Filter;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
/**
* Category filter allows to filter products collection using custom defined filters from search criteria.
*/
class ProductAttributeFilter implements CustomFilterInterface
{ 
protected $configurable;
protected $collectionFactory;
protected $registry;

public function __construct(
    Configurable $configurable,
    CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    Registry $registry
) {
    $this->registry = $registry;
    $this->configurable = $configurable;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
}

public function apply(Filter $filter, AbstractDb $collection)
{
    $conditionType = $filter->getConditionType();
    $attributeName = $filter->getField();
    $attributeValue = $filter->getValue();
    $category = $this->registry->registry('current_category'); 
   if($attributeName == 'language'){
        $conditions = [];
        foreach ($attributeValue as $value){
            $conditions[] = ['attribute'=>$attributeName, 'finset'=>$value];
        }
        $simpleSelect = $this->collectionFactory->create()
                        ->addAttributeToFilter($conditions);
 
    }else{
        $simpleSelect = $this->collectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeName, [$conditionType => $attributeValue]);
    }
 
    $simpleSelect->addAttributeToFilter('status', Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    if ($category) {
        $simpleSelect->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => (int)$category->getId()]);
    }
    
 
    $arr =  $simpleSelect;
    $entity_ids = [];
    foreach ($arr->getData() as $a){
        $entity_ids[] = $a['entity_id'];
    }
 
    $collection->getSelect()->where($collection->getConnection()->prepareSqlCondition(
        'e.entity_id', ['nin' => $entity_ids]
    ));
 
    return true;
}
}

6.Below is the GraphQl query which I am passing with the custom attributes to get the collection.
query {
          products(filter:
              {
                  category_id:{eq: "58"}
                  region: {in: [ "277"]}
                  language: {in: ["304"]}   
              }
              pageSize: 20
              currentPage: 1
              sort: {
                      price: DESC
                  }     
              )
              {
                  filters {
                            name
                            filter_items_count
                            request_var
                            filter_items {
                            label
                            value_string
                          }
              }       
                  items {
                       id
                       name
                       sku
                       type_id
                       short_description {
                           html
                       }
                       price {
                       regularPrice {
                       amount {
                           value
                           currency
                       }
                       }
                   }
                       }
                      total_count
                      page_info {
                         page_size
                      }
                  }
              }


It is not working. ProductAttributeFilter.php file is not even called. I have followed the same way that you have mentioned.

@AnkurVerma is there any error coming up while performing graphql ?

no, It seems it didn't called that class so graphql didn't called.
